# Search in files feature in developer console does not return all results

Tags: search

Has anyone noticed this before?

This is obviously broken.

[image]

~dzh

Comment: the line you have highlighted is in the same WebServices class ? but its not showing in the search results ? did you jus add that line and saved the file or was it already there when you opened the dev console ?

Comment: You have to save first (it can't search unsaved versions of a file), and it relies on indexing, meaning it can sometimes lag behind your saves. I've never observed a case where it has been saved and compiled for more than a few seconds and not get the results I expect.

Comment: Highlighted reference is something I've discovered manually. It's an old code, been there for years.

Comment: Something is not right. I have never used it (I always use the Eclipse Force.com environment), but when I experiment a bit with it now, the results are not really usable or predictable. I have one example of searching for a long method name, say longMethodName. Search finds that, but it cannot find longMethod or longMethodNam. And for other strings, the search works just as you expect it to. Strange...